# How to remove an object from a Mongoose model node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a node.js app using express and mongoose.

I have a model of a `listItem` which is a child of a `List`, which is a child of a `User`. I am successfully adding to the ListItem model when a user marks one of the `listItems` as bought.

E.g. This is the **listItem** model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var listItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    url: String,
    bought:Boolean,
    boughtBy: {
        name: String,
        id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
        }
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ListItem", listItemSchema);
```

And this is the code that adds the user who marked it as bought (it's inside a FindByIDAndUpdate() function)

```
//Add that it was bought and who bought it into model
updatedListItem.bought = boughtFlag;
updatedListItem.boughtBy.id = boughtByID;
updatedListItem.boughtBy.name = boughtByName;

//save model to DB
updatedListItem.save();
```

So this code works and the listItem model successfully shows the ID and name of the user that bought it. However, I now want to be able to remove that user from the object if they "Unmark it"

I've been trying this below but to no avail. How do I remove the `boughtBy` data from the model when a user clicks "Unmark"?
Have tried this:

```
$pull: {
  boughtBy: req.params.item_id 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove particular field from document you can use [$unset operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset)

```
ListItem.findOneAndUpdate(query, { "$unset": { "boughtBy": "" }}, options, callback)
```

We can change bought boolean and remove boughtBy field in one query:

```
ListItem.findOneAndUpdate(query, { "$unset": { "boughtBy": "" }, "$set": { "bought": false } }, options, callback)
```